# How to get customer profile detail in authorized.net in php

Tags: php, api, authorize.net

I want to retrive all customer profile detail as
1-customer first name
2-last name
cardit card number 
and all related customer data
 i am using sample code provided by authorized.net in php 
i am using 
`Get Customer Payment Profile()` function to retrive all data from authorized.net
but it gives me

```
GetCustomerPaymentProfile SUCCESS: Customer Payment Profile Id: 33211899
```

not the whole detail 
can anyone give suggestion

Answer (score 0):

The Sample code provided by Authorize.net gets the Payment Profile for server, but only displays the `PaymentProfileid`.

Thus, to get all the details you need to echo all the details

just modify these lines after getting the `$respone` object, it will give you the details you require.

```
if(($response != null)){
    if ($response->getMessages()->getResultCode() == "Ok")
    {
        echo "GetCustomerPaymentProfile SUCCESS: " . "\n";
        echo "Customer Payment Profile Id: " . $response->getPaymentProfile()->getCustomerPaymentProfileId() . "\n";
        echo "Credit Card Number: " . $response->getPaymentProfile()->getPayment()->getCreditCard()->getCardNumber() . "\n";
        echo "Credit Card Number: " . $response->getPaymentProfile()->getBillTo()->getFirstName() . "\n";
        echo "Credit Card Number: " . $response->getPaymentProfile()->getBillTo()->getLastName() . "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "GetCustomerPaymentProfile ERROR :  Invalid response\n";
        echo "Response : " . $response->getMessages()->getMessage()[0]->getCode() . "  " .$response->getMessages()->getMessage()[0]->getText() . "\n";
    }
}
else{
    echo "NULL Response Error";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i got it I have no words to thank you i have searching the probleam the whole day now i got it thanks again

Comment: Now i have only one confusion  this gives me  Credit Card Number in this format Credit Card Number: XXXX1111 now How i get the correct cradit card number?